# Twitter Bootstrap Element doesn't have height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following CSS Code.
My problem is that the DIV with the class `inventar` doesn't have a height.
I would prefer if the div has the height from the `img_div` elements.

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
   <h1>Inventar<small> Select for sale</small></h1>
   <hr class="akx"/>
   <div class="inventar">
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="25828822">
            <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="29840084">
           <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="17075550">
           <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="21142608">
            <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="23835624">
            <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="17654701">
            <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="13668573">
            <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="28821423">
            <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="23502203">
            <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="16881637">
            <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="23013673">
            <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="img_div" id="14411606">
            <img src="IMG LINK" alt="" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: a `div` doesn't have a height unless you put something in it, or apply height via CSS. Replace `IMG LINK` with an actual image, like `http://placehold.it/320x240` and you'll see height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post a jsfiddle with your CSS as well for the HTML you posted.
Without the CSS we wouldn't be able to help you.

Regardless, from your question it looks like the class `img_div` is floated.
If you are floating the elements you will need to clear them as well.

One way to get the height for `inventar` class is to give it [clearfix class](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

A common best practice in Bootstrap is to use .row as a parent to the columns, this is due to the floating issue @v.soni mentioned.

Also by default .row has a min-height 1px, and also negative margins so, you can nest an infinite amount of grids within a column.

so just add .row inside the .inventar and wrap the columns and everything should be fine.